# Cant send paginate meta data with response()->json

Tags: json, laravel, api, laravel-paginate

I have an api and I want to send some info to my clients.
I'm using resource collection to do this.

```
    return response()->json([
        'data' => ProductResource::collection(Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8)),
        'catdata' => CategoryResource::collection(Category::get()),
        'status' => "200"
    ]);
```

All things work but paginate meta data doesn't work.
It doesnt send paginate data.

Comment: you want to send fillter data come from request right ?

Comment: I want to use paginate in my app.

Comment: Can you tell me what criteria you select for filter like generally we filter in size,name etc and also share your table relationship

Answer (score 0):

API Resources are not meant to be used with each other, meaning that Laravel will not be able to detect that you want pagination metadata because you are converting to JSON before Laravel can read it. You would be better off separating your API responses, and having your clients call the API twice.

```
public function products()
{
     return ProductResource::collection(Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8));
}

public function categories()
{
     return CategoryResource::collection(Category::get());
}
```

You could also use the `additional` function on your `ProductResource::collection` call.

```
public function products()
{
     return ProductResource::collection(Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(8))->additional(['meta' => [
                'categories' => Category::get(),
            ]]);;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use one call, maybe its faster for clients.

Comment: @TopStars I've updated my answer for one API call that should include pagination.